# Run a WAR file in a remote host without manually starting tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web, deployment, war, openshift

I have a web app, that I can deploy and run on the localhost as a WAR only after manually starting the tomcat server.

If I want to deploy that web app as a WAR on a remote host for the rest of the world(!) is there any other way to do it, since users cannot (or do not need to) start the tomcat from that remote host.

So, basically, ...:8080/soda-w/Applicationclient/index.html works for localhost but not for the host like sofa.uqam.ca, for example.

Any step by step guidelines? Or suggestion?

Thanks...

Comment: what do you mean by "not need to start tomcat"? if there is a tomcat or another application server running in that remote host, you can deploy your application there

Comment: Hi
For example I have deployed it in OpenShift cloud provided by the Red Hat. I could deploy successfully, but the instance still does not run using the global URL for my app (that they give)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your war file to ROOT.war, so it gets deployed at the root context of your application server.  https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks. I did it already, and put it in the webapps folder of my openshift project. But it does not run and shows the 503 error.